# How to disable screen saver and power management in linux by command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, screensaver

Is there a command line you can run that can enable in-habitation, disabling computer going to screen saver, sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Forums [suggests](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1485005) the following:

```
gconftool --type int -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight/idle_dim_time ***time***
gconftool --type int -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_display_battery ***time***
gconftool --type int -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_computer_battery ***time***
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`xset`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xset.1.html) command controls a number of parameters of the X server (the part of the system that provides a graphical display with windows), including its built-in screen saver and blanking ability.

```
xset -dpms s off
```

If you're using a third party screensaver, it might still be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

When using LXDE (e.g. for running chromium in kiosk mode) you can remove the screensaver by editing `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` and remove `@xscreensaver -no-splash`.